# Cut a string recieved by jsoup

Tags: java, android, string, jsoup, cut

So this is my code, but every try to cut the string "words" fails, it just executes the TextView with the whole text recieved by the jsoup.

I just want to cut the first x words of the string.

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView texx;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // braus();
    texx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new http().execute();
        }
    });
}

public class http extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String words;
    String test;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite").get();
            words = doc.text();
            words.substring(100);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        texx.setText(words);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by the first x words ?  The returned String from jsoup would be the html source . And what exactly do you want to extract from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does nothing of use:

```
words.substring(100);
```

Yes, it produces a substring, but it then immediately discards the substring, it doesn't do anything with it, since you don't assign the result to anything, and it certainly does not change the String object still assigned to the words variable. Perhaps you wanted:

```
words = words.substring(100);
```

This gets the substring and assigns it back to the words variable.

This should be your mantra: *String objects are immutable*